# connecting as SYSDBA using roundhouse

Tags: roundhouse, sysdba

I want to connect as sysdba using roundhouse, already tried

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521))(CON
NECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)));uid=scott;pwd=tiger**;as sysdba**"
```

gut got this exception

```
RoundhousE encountered an error.
System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform t
o specification starting at index 202.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionSt
```

also tried

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521))(CON
NECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)));uid=scott;pwd=tiger;**DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;"**
```

but then the exception was

```
RoundhousE encountered an error.
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'dba privilege'.
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ConnectionStringAdmin` setting of the `<Roundhouse>` element to set the administration connection string. I tried using the `System` user but ran into different issues. I've asked the question on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469634/can-i-create-a-brand-new-oracle-db-schema-with-roundhouse) and on the project page [here](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/issues/107).

My issue was more related to creating a new database though, but the configuration settings that I have specified there might work for you.